# Terminology, is this a mixed effects logistic regression?

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, terminology, glmm

I have built this model in R and I am getting confused with the terminology.

For each individual `ID` I have a number of failures `fail` and successes `success` and one treatment.

```
mod1=glmer(cbind(fail,success)~treatment+(1|ID),family=binomial)
```

Is it correct to call this a mixed effects logistic regression?
Is it correct to say that this is a kind of GLMM?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you are correct that it is a generalised linear mixed effects model:

It is *generalised* because you have a non-continuous response variable and you are specifying a distribution family for it.

It is a *linear* model because it is linear in the parameters (because `glmer` fits linear models)

It is a *mixed effects* model because you have both a fixed effect (`treatment`) and a random effect (for `ID`).

It is also a *logistic* model because you specify `binomial` as the distribution family, and the link function in `glmer` when not specified explicitly is the canonical `logit`